# Polynomial maps of "close" operators (imitating continuity)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, functional-calculus

Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a Hilbert space. Let $L$ be another bounded linear operator satisfying $\|L\|<\varepsilon$. What can be said about the relationship between the spectra of $f(T),f(T+L)$ for $f\in \mathbb C[x]$ or between their operator norms?

I am motivated by the fact that for continuous $f$ and small $h$ we have $f(t+h)\approx f(t)$.

Since $L$ has a small spectral radius it seems reasonable to expect that $f(T+L)$ will have a similar spectrum to $f(T)$. I don't know how to tackle this though. Maybe some clever applications of the spectral mapping theorem and the functional calculus?

Comment: I think all you can say is that $\sigma(T+L)\subseteq \sigma(T)+B_\epsilon(0)$ and hence $\sigma[f(T+L)] \subseteq f[\sigma(T)+B_\epsilon(0)]$. Here you can use expansions like $f[\sigma(T)+B_\epsilon(0)]\subseteq f[\sigma(T)] + f'[\sigma(T)]\cdot B_\epsilon(0) +\frac12 f''[\sigma(T)]\cdot B_{\epsilon^2}(0) +....$

Comment: Dear @s.harp, why do we have $\sigma(T+L)\subseteq \sigma(T)+B_\epsilon(0)$?

Comment: Hmm it appears I hadn't thought so clearly about this. My idea works if $L$ and $T$ commute (here $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda-T)^{-n-1}L^n$ is an inverse of $\lambda-(T+L)$ if $\mathrm{dist}(\lambda,\sigma(T))>\epsilon$). But if they don't commute it doesn't look like you can write down an inverse via a power series. I wonder if its true (but it seems reasonable).